# Is there an equivalent in RoR for PHP's gmdate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, if I called:

```
gmdate("M-D-yTh:i:s")
```

Is there something similar for this case in RoR? I guess I could always DateTime.now.hour, DateTime.now.year, etc. etc. but that seems extremely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [strftime()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392) in Ruby's documentation on Time, which formats a time according to the directives in the given format string.

Comment: Ah ha, I thought that there might be something handy like that. That you know of is there anything equivalent to T in gmdate? Having played with this a bit it seems like RoR gives me %Z which is almost right but I really need the abbreviation.

Comment: You could look to the tzinfo gem, as mentioned [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95318) or [here](http://mad.ly/2008/04/09/rails-21-time-zone-support-an-overview/)